# How to exclude particular java folders and java files using ANT Build

Tags: java, ant, javac, build.xml

I'm using ANT build.xml for compile the java code and move the file into tomcat. Its working fine but now I've created multiple folders based on project requirement LIKE,

```
     com/abc/bean/abcbean.java
     com/abc/bean/model/abcmodel.java
     com/abc/bean/model/util/abcutil.java
```

So i want to exclude the files `com/abc/bean/model/abcmodel.java` and include other folders and files. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude files at compilation time, you may use options provided by javac ant task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html).
For instance:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
       destdir="${build}"
       includes="com/abc/**"
       excludes="com/abc/bean/model/*.java"/>
```

you may also use nested elements to do more complex filtering job (see ant documentation link above).